# Shrink covariance matrix in one direction

Tags: time-series, estimation, covariance, kalman-filter

I have implemented a Kalman Filter for position estimate $(x,y)$ on a robot, but now I have a problem. When I detect a landmark, I would like to correct my estimate only on a defined direction. As an example, if my robot is travelling on the plane, and meets a landmark with orientation 0 degrees, I want to correct the position estimate only on a direction perpendicular to the landmark itself (i.e. 90 degrees).

This is how I'm doing it for the position estimate:

1. I update $x_{posterior}$ as in the normal case, and store it in $x_{temp}$.
2. I calculate the error $e = x_{temp} - x_{prior}$.
3. I project this error vector $e$ on the direction perpendicular to the landmark to get $e' = \text{P}(e)$ where $\text{P}$ does the projection.
4. I add this projected quantity to $x_{prior}$ to get $x'_{posterior} := e' + x_{prior}$.

This is working quite well, but (**Question:**) how can I do the same for the covariance matrix? Basically, I want to shrink the covariance only on the direction perpendicular to the landmark.

Comment: I tried to make it a little easier to read. I also tried to introduce a few more formulas to keep track of what is told by words. Perhaps the notation could be improved further, that is up to you.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? 1. Even if the measurement is informative only about the "perpendicular direction", if the position in that direction is correlated to the position in the orthogonal direction (no different to the fact that a measurement measuring only one component of the state may be informative about the other components).  2. If you don't know your position, how do you know the direction to the landmark?   Also, what is the measurement here (is "0 degrees" part of the observation, or do you observe distance to a landmark with known coordinates, or what?)

Comment: Voting to close due to the aforementioned reasons. (if the observation model was clear, one could write an answer elaborating a solution that is not literally what is asked here)

Comment: I will add my solution, maybe it helps in clarifying what I meant at the time.

Comment: @charles It might still also be helpful to add the observation model  / why you want to do this - and how you handle the (presumably nonlinear) observation in the first place, using something like EKF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, that is just an approximation but it is working quite well.

Essentially this is what I do:

- I store the a priori covariance matrix in $P_{old}$.
- I execute the normal (uncorrected) update step, and store the covariance matrix in $P_{new}$.
- Given the direction of the landmark $d$, I compute the parallel component (to this direction $d$) of the axis of the ellipse represented by $P_{old}$. Then, I select the component with maximum length and store it in $a_{par}$.
- I compute the perpendicular component (to the same direction $d$) of the axis of the ellipse represented by $P_{new}$. Then, I select the component with maximum length and store it in $a_{perp}$.
- Finally I generate the corrected ellipse from the 2 axis $a_{par}$ and $a_{perp}$ and store the covariance matrix in $P$.

This is represented in the following example (direction of the landmark $d$ = 0°) figure, where the red ellipse is represented by $P_{old}$, the green ellipse by $P_{new}$, and the blue ellipse is the corrected one represented by $P$, where only the component perpendicular to $d$ has been shrunk.

[image]